# How to use only certain class object values in java?

Tags: java, function, class, oop

I'm still learning java and finding it pretty difficult and I have been quite stuck with this one for a while.

Say you have a class which has a constructor a bit like this:

```
public Fruit(String Name, String Type, double Price, int Stock) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Type = Type;
    this.Price = Price;
    this.Stock = Stock;
}
```

And say we have this object from this, such as:

```
Fruit fruit1 = new Fruit("Apple", "Apple", "0.45", 23);
```

And with this information I want to write a function which the user could enter then order the food. How could I use the information from this class object to use in a function?

Comment: Hint: please read about java naming conventions. Field names and parameters go camelCase, only class names start upper case.

Comment: I assume your function would be **within** the Fruit class.  In that case, you simply access those values the same way as demonstrated in the constructor, by adding `this.` in front of the value you want to use.  If you passed in a "quantity" parameter, you'd simply multiply it by `this.Price` and return the cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By simply later reading back these fields, maybe directly, or using getter methods you added, like:

```
if (someFruit.getName().equals(theNameOfSomeFoodOrderedByCustomer)) {
  System.out.println("you ordered " + someFruit.getName() + " that will cost you " + someFruit.getPrice());
```

From that point of you, you might want to research java getter/setter methods a bit more, to see examples for that.

Answer (score 1):

To access non-private member variables of one of your objects, use the `.` symbol, as follows:

```
Fruit apple = new Fruit("Apple", "Apple", "0.45", 23);
System.out.println(apple.price); //prints the price of the apple
```

In most cases, however, for the sake of encapsulation, it's recommended for you to use getter and setter methods. This way you can have better control of how your object's variables are accessed. Take a look at the following example:

```
private int price;  //a private member variable

//...

public int getPrice() {return this.price} //example of a getter method
public void setPrice(int nPrice) {this.price = nPrice;} //example of a setter method
```

In the example above you wouldn't be able to access the variable `price`directly outside its class. Instead, you would have to call the method `getPrice()`from an instance of `Fruit`.

**Note:** it's a good practice to start a variable name with a lower case.